# iOS SDK: Play two different sounds at the same time. One should respect the mute button, the other should not

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, avplayer, avaudiosession, mute

I want to play two sounds at the same time. One is a background sound and should respect the mute button but the other one is a recording that the user can optionally enable. If its enabled I want it to play no matter what the mute button is set to. Both sounds play at the same time.

I know how to force a sound to play with:

`[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];`

 and how to set it to respect the mute switch with:

`[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];`

But both sounds use the same session and if I have use one setting for one sound I get the same setting for the other.

I use AVAudioPlayer to play the sounds.

Is it possible to have one sound forced and the other to respect the mute switch?